# Map Application Image size issue?

Tags: html, image

I have created a Map Application which contain only one image and its image size is 13 MB which takes more loading time when I deploy to Production Server.

If I resize the image then all the coordinates of application which mapped change and quality of image also get worse.

Is there any way to Lazy Load or Partial rendering technique to load the image in application?

Comment: It would help to know what serverside technology (if any) you're using, as something like this could be helpful: https://github.com/martinheidegger/mapslice

Comment: I can move to asp.net if there is any good solution is available

Answer (score 0):

When you resize the image define only ONE: Either height or width. The aspect ratio should fix itself automatically. From all the details you have given me, that is all I can help you with.